# How to upgrade app shell of a PWA (Progressive Web App)

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I was wondering if there's a way to upgrade the app shell of a PWA (Progressive Web App) after the PWA has been installed on the user's phone.

Comment: A progressive web app rely on Service Workers to optimise resources loading. The app shell is no exception. With what tool do you need an example ? Sw-toolbox ? Angular-mobile ? Do you already have an existing progressive web app in development ? Be more specific please ...

Comment: @noelmace sorry about this vague question. I just started learning PWA and am trying my best to make the question clear. Now I realize that service workers will handle the update of resources. Thanks!

Comment: Oh ok so my comment is the answer you needed, cool :-) i'll move It, please validate It in order to "close" the question. I'll give you some more infos when / if I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A progressive web app rely on Service Workers to optimise resources loading. The app shell is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try take a look at [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache) too to facilitate caching & versioning of resources.

Alternatively you could manage it yourself through simple versioning. Ultimately the important part is to notify the application that the resources need to be updated by invalidating the cache. The same applies for any static files.